# Rvest está retornando o seguinte erro ao ler uma página: {xml_nodeset (0)}, como resolver?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Gostaria de criar uma ferramenta para fazer web scraping no site da Câmara dos deputados do rio de janeiro, mas estou esbarrando no problema de sequer conseguir ler a página web.

Alguém sabe por que a função `read_html` está retornando o valor `{xml_nodeset (0)}`?

Segue o código:

```
scrap <- read_html("http://www.camara.rj.gov.br/controle_atividade_parlamentar.php?m1=materias_leg&m2=10a_Leg&m3=prolei&url=http://mail.camara.rj.gov.br/APL/Legislativos/scpro1720.nsf/Internet/LeiInt?OpenForm")

scrap %>%
  html_nodes("h1")


#Resposta: {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Comment: Isso não é uma mensagem de erro, é um valor de retorno da função `html_nodes` que significa que não o valor `"h1"` não foi encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou claro na pergunta o que você está buscando na página, acredito que sejam os projetos de lei.

Normalmente, tabelas em `HTML` usam a `class = table`. Por trás das cenas creio que a função `read_html` procura essa tag de tabela, se ela não encontra, a busca retorna vazia e o código falha.

Os projetos de lei estão em um `iframe`, que é uma janela em `HTML` dentro de outra página em `HTML`. Logo, você precisa primeiramente buscar o link desse `iframe` para depois fazer o scraping dos dados.

Esse código irá buscar o `iframe` para você:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

html_url <- "http://www.camara.rj.gov.br/controle_atividade_parlamentar.php?m1=materias_leg&m2=10a_Leg&m3=prolei&url=http://mail.camara.rj.gov.br/APL/Legislativos/scpro1720.nsf/Internet/LeiInt?OpenForm"

html_iframe <- read_html(x = html_url) %>%
  html_nodes(css = "iframe") %>%
  html_attr("src")

html <- read_html(html_iframe[1])
```

Perceba que o objeto `html_iframe` vai conter o link e agora, usando a função `read_html` irá retornar um objeto com os dados.